# Get ith elements in numpy nested arrays given an array of indices (i1, i2, ...)

Tags: python, numpy

Given `x`, a numpy array:

```
>>> x
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

And another array / list of indices:

```
>>> indices = [2, 1, 1]
```

Is there a numpy method that takes both as input:

```
>>> np.some_method(x, indices, axis=1)
```

And returns:

```
array([ 3,  6, 10])  # for the given indices (2, 1, 1) respectively
```

Comment: What is the relation between (2,1,1) to (3,6,10)

Comment: @LiorCohen indices of an element for every nested array respectively

Answer (score 1):

As @Dani mentioned in the comments, you can use advanced indexing:

```
x[np.arange(3), indices]
```